# Adding entries sequentially to an empty pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am encountering pretty strange behavior. If I let

```
dict = {'newcol':[1,5], 'othercol':[12,-10]}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=dict)
print df['newcol']
```

I get back a pandas Series object with 1 and 5 in it. Great.

```
print df
```

I get back the DataFrame as I would expect. Cool.

But what if I want to add to a DataFrame a little at a time? (My use case is saving metrics for machine learner training runs happening in parallel, where each process gets a number and then adds to only that row of the DataFrame.)

I can do the following:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame()
df['newcol'] = pandas.Series()
df['othercol'] = pandas.Series()
df['newcol'].loc[0] = 1
df['newcol'].loc[1] = 5
df['othercol'].loc[0] = 12
df['othercol'].loc[1] = -10
print df['newcol']
```

I get back the pandas Series I would expect, identical to creating the DataFrame by the first method.

```
print df
```

I see printed that df is an Empty DataFrame with columns [newcol, othercol].

Clearly in the second method the DataFrame's contents are equivalent to the first method. So why is it not smart enough to know it is filled? Is there a function I can call to update the DataFrame's knowledge of its own Series so all these (possibly out-of-order) Series can be unified in to a consistent DataFrame?

Comment: I think when you saying `df['newcol'].loc[0] = 1` your actually editing the `series` and not the `dataframe`. Use `df.loc[0, 'col']` like in @Vaishali's answer

Comment: Yes, but the DataFrame points to that Series, so it's odd it doesn't reflect the changes. @Vaishali's method updates both because you're telling the DataFrame to update itself, and then it manages updating the Series also. All this evidently means that when you ask a DataFrame about itself, it doesn't gather data from its constituent Series at query-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be able to assign data to an empty dataframe using following

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['newcol'] = pd.Series()
df['othercol'] = pd.Series()
df.loc[0, 'newcol'] = 1
df.loc[1, 'newcol'] = 5
df.loc[0, 'othercol'] = 12
df.loc[1, 'othercol'] = -10

    newcol  othercol
0   1.0     12.0
1   5.0     -10.0
```

Comment: An additionally useful detail for all you noobs out there: It isn't necessary to set df['column'] = a pandas Series here. Exclude those lines, and everything still works just fine.